# Google Maps v3 with Openlayers - First Zoom Level

Tags: openlayers-2, javascript, google-maps

I use Google Maps v3 in my application and I noticed a strange behavior, When I refresh the web page, the map zoomed out to display the whole map then get back to the zoom level I specify in my code. This happen fast but every time I refresh the page. How can I fix it?

**EDIT**

Part of mu code:

```
var geographic = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326");
var mercator = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:3857");
maxExtent: new OpenLayers.Bounds(-20037508, -20037508, 20037508, 20037508.34).transform(geographic,mercator);

map = new OpenLayers.Map('map',{
        projection: new OpenLayers.Projection('EPSG:3857'), 
        displayProjection: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326")
 });

 gmap = new OpenLayers.Layer.Google("Google",{ numZoomLevels: 20});  
 map.addLayers([gmap]);
```

Comment: Can we see the live code it is much easier to debug using firebug.

Comment: Your example doesn't even run up correctly: http://jsfiddle.net/XRr6S/2/ - you cannot zoom, move the map etc. And you specify no zoom level! I guess `numZoomLevels` is something else and also cannot be found in the [documentation](http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Layer/Google-js.html#OpenLayers.Layer.Google.Properties)